# Animate an image size on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Im trying to animate a large image so it changes dimensions, starts at (200x116)px and becomes (400x232)px on click and then would revert back to (200x116)px if clicked again,

Here's a link to the code: http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/FMfC4/1/

HTML:

```
<img id="imgtab" src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
#imgtab {
    position:relative;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgtab").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
        $("#imgtab").animate({
            width: "200px"
            height: "116px"
        });
    }, function () { // fired the second time 
        $("#imgtab").animate({
            width: "400px"
            height: "232px"
        });
    });
});
```

Clicking the image should make it animate from small to large but it doesn't seem to change. Can anyone suggest what to change and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thats not how `.toggle()` works. At least not in newer versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you simply want to toggle on click, try below

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var small={width: "200px",height: "116px"};
        var large={width: "400px",height: "232px"};
        var count=1; 
        $("#imgtab").css(small).on('click',function () { 
            $(this).animate((count==1)?large:small);
            count = 1-count;
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgtab" class='small' src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg">
```

OR

you can also use the duration parameter of `addClass` and `removeClass` functions available in **jQuery-ui widgets** library. i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count=1; 
    $("#imgtab").on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('small, large',400);
        $this.addClass((count==1)?'large':'small',400);
        count = 1-count;
    })
});
```

where `.small` and `.large` css classes are :

```
.small{
    width:200px;
    height:116px;
}
.large{
    width:400px;
    height:232px;
}
```

see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FMFc4/35/).

**NOTE:** you will need reference of jQuery UI library also, cause duration parameter of `addClass` and `removeClass` is available there only.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing comma between object properties passed as a argument in `animate` method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgtab").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
        $("#imgtab").animate({
            width: "200px",//HERE
            height: "116px"
        });
    }, function () { // fired the second time 
        $("#imgtab").animate({
            width: "400px",//HERE
            height: "232px"
        });
    });
});
```

EG: http://jsfiddle.net/dFU9P/

Comment: The OP's fiddle uses jQuery 1.9.1. Your example uses a 1.6.4 and doesn't behave the same way in later version. `.toggle()` hides and shows elements.

Comment: I didnot realize that jquery was in 1.9 , it that case he need to have a 'click' event with some flag, else use jquery migarte plugin to achieve the same behaviour with 'toggle'

Comment: not sure how i missed that! is there a way i can change it so it works with jQuery 1.9?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way you can achieve your animation effect without having to use jQuery's animate and instead use CSS animations. I don't know what browsers you need to support, but it is still nice to see how it can be done in different ways.

HTML:

```
<img id="imgtab" src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 116px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in; //added vendor prefixes for older browsers
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in; //first parameter decides what properties to animate
    -m-transition: all .4s ease-in; // second is duration
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in; //3rd is the timing-function
       transition: all .4s ease-in;
}

.fullSize {
    height: 400px;
    width: 232px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#imgtab').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('fullSize');
});
```

And here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AtQwM/. Feel free to mess around with the transition parameters for different effects!

Answer (score 0):

`Toggle` offers two states for one event but any animation using it ends up with `display:none`. You therefore need to use your own toggling mechanism using a variable to control the state of the image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imgSmall = false

    $('#imgtab').on('click',function() {
        $("#textab").toggle(20);
        if ( imgSmall ) {
            $('#imgtab').animate({width:"400px",height:"232px"});
            imgSmall = false
        } else {
            $('#imgtab').animate({width:"200px",height:"116px"});
            imgSmall = true
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FMfC4/3/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the new image dimension in the code they could be data-attributes.
http://jsfiddle.net/FMfC4/8/

```
<img class="imgtab" src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg" data-width="400" data-height="200">

(function($) {
$.fn.imageSizer = function() {

    var originalSize = {
        width: this.width(),
        height: this.height()
    };

    this.on('click', function() {
        var newSize = {
            width: $(this).data('width'),
            height: $(this).data('height')
        };

        var currentSize = ($(this).width() == newSize.width) ? originalSize : newSize;

        $(this).animate(currentSize);
    });    
}
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".imgtab").imageSizer();
});
```